# Как построить из списка вершин и дуг матрицу смежности?

Tags: c#

Даны вершины : 1,2,3,4,5
И дуги, к примеру : (1:2 , 2:3 , 3:4 , 4:4)
Необходимо из этих данных сделать матрицу смежности, код который сейчас есть:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp29
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите n");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] A = new int[n];
            Console.WriteLine("Введите массив А");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                A[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine("Введите количесвто cтолбцов (m)");
            int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите количесвто строк (n)");
            int l = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[,] B = new int[k, l];
            int u;
            u = k - 1;
            int[,] C = new int[u, u];
            Console.WriteLine("массив B");
            for (int e = 0; e < k; e++)
            {
                for (int g = 0; g < l; g++)
                    B[e, g] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Вершины");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                Console.Write(A[i] + " ");

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Дуги");

            for (int e = 0; e < k; e++)
            {
                for (int g = 0; g < l; g++)
                    Console.Write(B[e, g] + "\t");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Матрица смежности");
            for (int e = 0; e < k; e++)
            {
                for (int g = 0; g < l; g++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < u; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < u; j++)
                        {
                            C[e - 1, g - 1] = 1;

                            Console.Write(C[e, g] + "\t");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно построить матрицу смежности.
n- количество вершин , A[]- список вершин
k - столбцы, l-строки, сделано это для удобства чтение дуг, примерно такой вывод:
1 2
2 3
B - это как раз матрица со списком k,l
С- это для того чтобы сделать матрицу смежности
Пример исходных данных:
Вводим вершины: 1,2,3,4,5,6
Вводим дуги: 1,2; 1,4; 2,3; 3,3; 4,2; 5,2; 5,6; 6,6;
Должна получится матрица смежности:
0 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: что такое `n`, `A[]`, `B[]`, `C[]`? Я не понимаю что вводится. Что обозначают эти буквы?

Comment: Попробуйте называть переменные словами, код станет значительно легче читать.

Comment: окей, видимо, `C[]` это матрица смежности, `A[n]` - список вершин, но что такое `B[]`? "матрица ДУГ"?

Comment: добавил пояснение

Comment: в чём смысл ввода списка вершин, если вершины пронумерованы от нуля до `n`?

Comment: Просто обозначить их количество и какие вообще существуют, если есть совет, как это лучше сделать - я не откажусь от него

Comment: Ну, числа n достаточно, чтобы узнать, какие есть вершины

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: ```
Пример n: 5
A[i] = 1,2,3,4,5
B[e,g] = 1 2 , 3 4 , 2 2 , 4 5, 5 3
```

Comment: Пример лучше перенести в текст вопроса и добавить ожидаемую матрицу смежности

Comment: @iKuzmychov добавил

Answer (score 1):

Если вы вводите дуги вручную, то можете запрашивать либо:

-строку, содержащую список дуг - подобно вашему " 1,2; 1,4; 2,3; 3,3; 4,2; 5,2; 5,6; 6,6". В этом случае делите (Split) строку по разделителям ";", затем каждую из получившихся подстрок по разделителю ",", преобразуете в пару чисел `i, j` и устанавливаете

```
 С[i-1, j-1] = 1;
 C[j-1, i-1] = 1; //если граф ненаправленный
```

-либо  по отдельности начальную и конечную вершину дуги, и так же устанавливаете соотв. элементы матрицы смежности

Comment: Спасибо, а как можно будет из этого сделать матрицу смежности, с вводом понятно

Comment: Матрицу вы уже создали здесь `int[,] C = new int[k, k];`, она заполнена нулями, как я понимаю. И при вводе дуг вы некоторые элементы меняете на единицы. Вот и всё.

Comment: можете пожалуйста немного с программой помочь?Не понимаю как это инициализировать, на словах звучит проще чем кажется, я совсем новичок в си шарпе

Comment: `с вводом понятно` - вы получаете пару чисел - номера вершин для очередной дуги? Остальное я уже написал

Comment: Выдает ошибку с диапазоном значений : "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" , в самом вопросе исправил на тот код, который есть